# Binding covariance collection WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, covariance

I'm have:

```
public class BaseSong 
{    
    public string Artist
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get; set;
    }

public class ExtendedSong : BaseSong
{
    public string Bitrate { get; set;}
    ...
}

public class CollectionSong<T> : ObservableCollection<T>  where T : BaseSong
{
    ...
}
public class Playlist
{
    CollectionSong _collectionSong;
    public CollectionSong<BaseSong> Collection
    { 
         get { return _collectionSong; }
         set {...}
    }
    public Playlist()
    {}
    ...
}
```

I can so

```
Playlist plist= new Playlist();
plist.Collection = new CollectionSong<BaseSong>();
plist.Collection.Add(new ExtendedSong(){...});

ListView lv = new ListView();
lv.ItemSource = plist.Collection;
```

But, how i can say ListView about show listViewItem as ExtendedSong and don't BaseSong?

P.S. collection have only BaseSong items or only ExtendedSong

```
private ListView CreateListView(PlaylistViewModel model)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.ListView lv = new System.Windows.Controls.ListView();
            lv.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Collection")
            {
                Source = model,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            });
            lv.SetBinding(ListView.ViewProperty, new Binding("ColumnConfig")
                {
                    Converter = new VkPlayer.Helpers.ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter()
                });
            return lv;
        }
DataTemplate songLayout = new DataTemplate();
            songLayout.DataType = typeof(ExtendedSong);

            FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            spFactory.Name = "textBoxFactory";
            spFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Bitrate"));
            songLayout.VisualTree = spFactory;
ColumnConfig = new ColumnConfig { Columns = new List<Column> { 
                new Column { Header = "Title", DataField = "FullName" }, 
                new Column { Header = "Bitrate", Template = songLayout}
                 }
            };

  public class ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var config = value as ColumnConfig;
            if (config != null)
            {
                var grdiView = new GridView();
                foreach (var column in config.Columns)
                {
                    var grwCol = new GridViewColumn { Header = column.Header };
                    if (column.DataField != null)
                    {
                        var binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(column.DataField);
                        if (column.Converter != null)
                            binding.Converter = column.Converter as System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter;
                        if (column.ConverterParameter != null)
                        {
                            binding.ConverterParameter = column.ConverterParameter;
                        }
                        grwCol.DisplayMemberBinding = binding;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grwCol.CellTemplate = column.Template;
                    }
                    grdiView.Columns.Add(grwCol);
                }
                return grdiView;
            }
            return System.Windows.Data.Binding.DoNothing;
        }
```

Dont work, output:
 System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Bitrate' property not found on 'object' ''BaseSong' (HashCode=23764897)'

Comment: Cast your collection as ExtendedSongs Collection since derived class can be cast to base class.

Comment: I'm need show as ExtendedSong at several listview and other as BaseSong. How I can show as ExtendedSong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF, we use `DataTemplate`s to define what our data objects should look like in the UI. Please see the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information about data binding. Therefore, we can simply declare a `DataTemplate` for each of your data types and the content of each `DataTemplate` will have access to the properties from that type. Try something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:BaseSong}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:ExtendedSong}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bitrate}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionSong" ... />
```

That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CollectionSong<T> : ObservableCollection<T>  where T : BaseSong
{
   public CollectionSong<ExtendedSong> ToExSongs() {...}
}
public CollectionSong<BaseSong> CollectionEx
    { 
         get { return Collection.ToExSongs(); }
         set {...}
    }
```